# Why do I always get BUSY when using WifiP2pManager?

Tags: android, p2p, wifi-direct

I am trying to connect two Android-Devices using Wi-Fi Direct.

On my HTC-Phone (One SV) it seems to work, but with my second device a LG Optimus 4xhd it doesnt work.

In my onResume() function I start the following thread:

```
new Thread(){
        private int count=0;
        public void run()
        {
            mManager.discoverPeers(mChannel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    Log.d(tag,"SUCCESS - started discovering peers");

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int reason) {
                    count++;

                    String err=new String();
                    if(reason==WifiP2pManager.BUSY) err="BUSY";
                    if(reason==WifiP2pManager.ERROR)err="ERROR";
                    if(reason==WifiP2pManager.P2P_UNSUPPORTED) err="P2P_UNSUPPORTED";
                    Log.d(tag,"FAIL - couldnt start to discover peers code: "+err+" ("+count+")");
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if(count>=20)return;
                    mManager.discoverPeers(mChannel, this);
                }
            });
        }
    }.start();
```

As I said before: this works fine on my HTC.
But with the LG I just get "FAIL - couldnt start to discover peers code: BUSY" (20 times).

I also tried WifiP2pManager.createGroup() with the same result.

Another thing that I realized is, that my BroadcastReceiver with the following filters doesnt receive anything on my LG (HTC gets some broadcasts).
Filters:

```
 filter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
    // Indicates a change in the list of available peers.
    filter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
    // Indicates the state of Wi-Fi P2P connectivity has changed.
    filter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);
    // Indicates this device's details have changed.
    filter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION);
```

I am not trying any fancy stuff. I'm just following the Api-Guides for Wi-Fi Direct on http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html

Is there anything I can do? I cant understand why the LG-Phone should work that different.

Just to make one last thing sure: In my onCreate() I get and Init my Manager as followed:

```
 mManager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(MainActivity.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
    mChannel = mManager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), receiver);
```

And it seems to work on both devices. (I get a Channel back)

Comment: Do you get any solution for this ?

Answer (score -1):

you using `mainLooper` so don't create any thread and do all the , and do some thing like this:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.search_devices:
            if(!isWifiP2pEnabled){
                Toast.makeText(this, "enable wifi p2p", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            }
            onInitiateDiscovery();
            manager.discoverPeers(channel, MainActivity.this);

            default: 
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
```